# Can C++ return different memory address for same variable with & operator?

Tags: c++, multithreading, microprocessors

If two or more processor cores copy a variable into their local cache, how C++ handles that? Does &var return a different memory address depending on which core executed that instruction?

Comment: Processor caches don't have separate address spaces. Copying happens transparently and doesn't change the address.

Comment: `&var` may have different values at different times, if `var` is a named variable with automatic storage duration.  So, say, it may (or may not) have a different address every time the containing function is called.   So `void f() {int var; std::cout << (void *)&var;}  int main() {f(); f();}`  is not guaranteed to produce the same output for the two calls of `f()`.   But that has nothing to do with which cpu or core computes `&var` - it is related to lifetime of variables.

Answer (score 7):

The address you get is the logical address in RAM not the address in cache. Its the cache controllers job to 'know' what RAM address are in what parts of its caches

Comment: It's the address in *the process' address space*. That could be virtualized multiple times.

Comment: It should be pointed out that cache coherence is an issue though and depending on the architecture different memory access fencing / barrier models exist. This becomes visible for example in atomic access specifiers. Also explicit memory fencing instructions exist.

Comment: @datenwolf but I will always see the same address, coherence, racing, barriers etc are different issues

Comment: I would hope that the standard has language to specify that an object's pointer in program space doesn't change until it is destroyed, but I wouldn't know where to look.

Comment: @pm100 yes, it will be the same address. But reads from that "same" address are not guaranteed to deliver the same value, unless memory access ordering is taken care of.

Comment: @datenwolf the question was 'is the address the same', not 'is the value the same'

Comment: @datenwolf Yes, that wasn't the question at all.

Comment: ...But, see the comment by @peter on the original question. `&x` does _not_ have to yield the same address every time it's executed if `x` is a local variable in a function. That's because the name, `x` actually refers to a _different_ variable in each activation of the function. The variable is created on the stack each time the function is called, and it is destroyed each time the function returns. If more than one call can be active at the same time (e.g., because of recursion or multi-threading) then multiple `x`s can exist at different addresses at the same time.